# Are these transliterations of 11th dynasty names plausibly formed?

Tags: ancient-greek, transliteration, egyptian, hieroglyphs

Question:

Are Mentophis (Μεντῶφις), Monton (Μωντων), and Anatophis (Ἀνατοφις) plausible Greek (and Latin) names for Mentuhotep, Montu, and Intef respectively?

Background:

Manetho's Egyptian chronicle doesn't mention any kings of the 11th dynasty, but we know from other sources it consisted of kings with common names Intef and Mentuhotep.

It's uncertain whether these names were ever transliterated into Greek, but I'm wondering what they *could* have looked like if they were?

My attempt:

*Mentuhotep*

I tried Mentuhotep first. This one is a bit easy, since parts of the name were already transliterated into Greek. The Pharaoh *Amenhotep*, for example, became Amenophis (Ἀμένωφις; once as Amenophthis, though only in Africanus, if it has been copied correctly). I can't see a reason why -ωφις wouldn't be used for -hotep here.

With Mentu-, we don't have it as an initial stem, but we do have it as a second root in the name of the city Hermonthis (Ἕρμωνθις, modern [Armant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armant,_Egypt)). This leads me to believe that the Mont- would have been a part of the name of the god (so, perhaps Μωντων). I'm guessing that there might be some sort of vowel weakening when in the beginning of the name by the times the Greeks would have become familiar with it, such as it was with Amoun/Amen-. We know that the Egyptians (in Plutarch's day, so quite a bit later than Manetho) pronounced `jmn` "Αμουν" (though the Greeks wrote it Ἄμμων; see [Plut. *De Iside* 9](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A2008.01.0239%3Asection%3D9)), yet with names like `jmn-htp` Manetho has Ἀμένωφις, not Αμουνωφις or Αμμωνωφις. Perhaps something similar is going on with Montu?

The -u (.w in Egyptian) would then contract (or assimilate?) into an omega, yielding Μεντωφις.

Edit for more evidence of vowel changes in Egyptian:

You also get a shift from u -> e, as can be seen from the name of "Set(h)", which originally seems to have been pronounced something like *šutaḫ*. Te Valde points out that at some point *u* turns into *e*, yielding the Greek transliteration Σηθ.

*Intef*

Intef is trickier, because I don't see anything comparable. The Egyptian name is jnj-jt.f. Following the transliteration of jnm as "Amun", I think using an alpha is appropriate. The first part could then transliterated as Ανατ-, which would fit the Greek pattern of using a similar-sounding Greek word to shape the transliteration (cf. [ἄνατος](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Da)%2Fnatos)).

For the second part of the name, the .f in jnj-jt.f is a pronominal suffix, and thus, especially by late Egyptian, likely only weakly working here. The closest I can find phonetically is [Bakenranef](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bakenranef), whose Latin/Greek name is Bocchoris (Βόκχωρις) or maybe Bochchoris (Βόχχωρις). The suffix disappears completely. However, another Egyptian name for Bakenranef is Wahkare, and I'm guessing this is where the Greek actually comes from. With [Dynasty 4 pharaohs](https://pharaoh.se/comparing-manetho), the -f- in their name either disappears completely or is transliterated with a phi.

Looking specifically at that final -f, in Dynasty 6 you have two kings with the name Nemtiemsaf, which in Greek is rendered -ouphis (οῦφις). The hieroglyph before the .f though is sȝ (Gardiner's V16), which explains the length of the vowel. This isn't present with Intef, and so I use a simple omicron instead: Ανατοφ-. Finally, with the ending, there doesn't seem to be any consistent reason why -is or -es, but I just kept it -is following the example from Nemtiemsaf, yielding Ανατοφις.

As a side note, of course, I know that you cannot predict which Pharaonic name will be used, but just looking at the common name, are these conjectures plausible? Have I made any glaring errors here? And what of the accents?

Comment: When first reading this, I was going to make a comment about how there's no difference between Mentu and Montu, there's just a convention to add spurious E's and O's to make the words pronounceable in conversation (unless we have a Greek transcription to use, as in jmn > Amon). But you clearly have experience with Egyptian so I think it's me who's missing something. So: why put the epsilon in there?

Comment: @Draconis I'm not sure I'm on the surest ground with this thinking, but I was thinking analogically with Amoun/Amen- that there might be some sort of vowel weakening. We know that the Egyptians (in Plutarch's day, so quite a bit later than Manetho) pronounced Amun "Αμουν" (though the Greeks wrote it differently), yet with names like jmn-htp, we get "Ἀμένωφις", not "Αμουνωφις" or "Αμμωνωφις". I thought perhaps something might be going on with Montu. As for the actual vowel there, it's an omega in the city name Ἕρμωνθις, which I assume was a Hellenized form combining Hermes and Montu.

Comment: I'm no expert in Egyptian, so maybe I'm missing something in the logic.